# req.user data is undefined when sending a request from the client to the api

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, passport.js, passport-local

So... when I access the route http://localhost:5000/api/isLoggedIn manually I get the user info (req.user) but not when I send a get request through the client (next.js) like why is this happening is it a config error for protection?
here is the code

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const cors = require("cors")
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express()

const db_url = process.env.DB_URL
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const User = require("./modules/User")
mongoose.connect(db_url).then((res) => {
    console.log("successfuly connected to db")
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: process.env.SECRET, resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { httpOnly: true, secure: false, expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 } }))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.debug = true;

const isLoggedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
}

app.post("/api/register", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        const user = new User({ email, username })
        const newUser = await User.register(user, password)
        req.login(newUser, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        );
        await newUser.save()
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/login' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
    });


app.get("/api/logout", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    req.session.destroy(err => {
        if (err) return next(err)
    })
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
})

app.get("/api/isLoggedIn", (req, res) => {
    try {
        // if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        //     res.json({ isLoggedIn: true })
        // } else {
        //     res.json({ isLoggedIn: false })
        // }
        res.send(req.user)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 5000")
})
```

and here is the get request from the client (it shows undefined)

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/isLoggedIn").then((res) => {
            setTimeout(() => console.log(res.data), 1000)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

i would really appreciate some help

i tried changing some session configurations to look and see if it's a protection problem but no success

Comment: You don't use any middleware and `req.user` isn't there by default

Comment: How do i see req.user when i access the url manually not through a request then?